Decoding Dictionary depending on ClassType
Let's say I have a variable clients: [String: Client]. Client is my parent class where I have a subclass SpecialClient. Both classes are Codable, and I want to decode from a JSON string into the dictionary. In this dictionary, I want to have both types of clients.
For that, every client in the JSON string has a variable clientType which defines if it is a SpecialClient or not. I now need to read this value and add a SpecialClient or a normal Client to the dictionary based on it.
Currently, I just have something like this, which obviously just produces Clients in the dictionary. I did some research but could not find a way.
class Object: Codable {
    var clients: [String:Client]


    init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.clients = try container.decode([String : Client].self, forKey: .clients)
    }
}

Have a container with clients from Client and SpecialClient class.
For more context: JSON looks like this:
{
  "groups": {
    "GroupId1": {
      "label": "group1",
      "id": "GroupId1"
    },
    "GroupId2": {
      "label": "group2",
      "id": "GroupId2"
    }
  },
  "clients": {
    "ClientId1": {
      "clientType": "APP",
      "label": "client1"
    },
    "ClientId2": {
      "clientType": "SPECIAL",
      "label": "Client2",
      "specialValue": 2
    }
  }
}


First decode clientType and then use a switch on that value to decode the corresponding client subclass?

I assume there other data field differences in the json between the parent and child classes?  As if not you could decode them all as Client and then iterate through the array and transform based on clientType.

Yes that seems like the correct approach. Can you give a small idea how it should look? Tried it already, but it did not work the way I implemented.

@flanker yes there are other data field differences, which i need

Assumed so :)  @JoakimDanielson's approach would be the proper one.  However depending on how/where the code is being used, and how big the differences between the classes are, a quick, dirty, and hacky approach is to create a temporary class with all the properties of the two, with the differences optional, allow Decodable to do the work, and then map into the final data structures.  Not best practice(so not adding as an answer!) but easily built/tweaked if all you want to do is get data into a personal project!

@flanker thanks for your ideas, but its in a business environment so I will try to do it the proper way :D

@JoakimDanielson added the json for more context. the problem I have is I don't know how to decode the clientType because it's inside the class I want to decode. Maybe you have an idea?

Re-reading the question I see that you have only two types, Client and SpecialClinet, so then I would simply first try to decode into one type and if that fails decode into the other.

If you are responsible for the backend consider to send a more suitable, Codable compliant JSON, for example two arrays one for each client type and with the clientId1111 identifier as a property inside the type, at least something which can be decoded without implementing init(from:).

The example json structure isn't valid, so it's not helping come up with an answer.  The mix of arrays/dictionaries doesn't make sense in terms of the question.  Can you post the (cleansed) actual json?

EDIT the OP clarified the JSON structure - it is a single heterogenous dictionary rather than an array of multiple homogenous dictionaries -  and the initial approach is no longer appropriate.  However leaving the answer here as it may prove useful to future searches.  Revised answer is at the end.

Initial answer for multiple homogenous dictionaries
There's an assumption made in this answer due to the lack of clarity in the question around the JSON structure.  I've assumed the structure is:
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "clientId1111": {
        "clientType": "BASIC_TYPE",
        "label": "Test1"
      }
    },
    //...
    {
      "clientId1114": {
        "clientType": "SPECIAL_TYPE",
        "label": "Test4",
        "specialCode": 4
      }
    }
  ]
}

i.e. an array of dictionaries, keyed at the top level by clients   if this isn't the case you may need to adapt the answer.
On this basis I've created a number of models:
The base Client model.  This complies with Decodable out the box so no custom decoding is required.
class Client: Decodable {
   let label: String
   let clientType: String
   
   init(label: String, clientType: String) {
      self.label = label
      self.clientType = clientType
   }
}

The SpecialClient model:
class SpecialClient: Client {
   let specialCode: Int //just to differentiate from Client
   enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
      case label, clientType, specialCode
   }
   
   required init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      specialCode = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .specialCode)
      let label = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .label)
      let type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .clientType)
      super.init(label: label, clientType: type)
   }
}

This uses a custom decoder and calls super.init with the data fields.  [I feel there is a better way to handle this but it's so long since I've used inheritance with coddle...!]
and then the bulk of the decoding happens in the Object model

class Object: Decodable {
   var clients: [String:Client]
   
   enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
      case clients
   }
   
   
   required init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
      var imports = [ [String: Client] ]()
      do {
         let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
         var dataContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .clients)
         while !dataContainer.isAtEnd {
            do {
               let imported = try dataContainer.decode([String: SpecialClient].self)
               imports.append(imported)
            } catch {
               let imported = try dataContainer.decode([String: Client].self)
               imports.append(imported)
            }
         }
      } catch {
         fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
      }
      clients = imports.reduce(into:[String: Client]()){ master, childDict in  
         childDict.forEach{  childPair in
            master[childPair.key] = childPair.value
         }
      }
   }
}

here it uses a nested unkeyed container so you can access both the dictionary key (the clientId###) and its value (either a Client or a SpecialClient).
The method iterates through each entry in the unkeyed container and for each initially tries to decode the more specialised child  class, and then if that fails tries to decode the simpler parent class in the catch block. The decoded pair of values, i.e. the [String: Client/SpecialClient] dictionary, is appended to a temporary array.
Finally it reduced (flattens) the temporary array of dictionaries into the main clients dictionary.
Working on my test json, object.clients.forEach{print($0)} produces this output:
(key: "clientId1114", value: __lldb_expr_18.SpecialClient)
(key: "clientId1112", value: __lldb_expr_18.Client)
(key: "clientId1111", value: __lldb_expr_18.Client)
(key: "clientId1113", value: __lldb_expr_18.SpecialClient)

as expected.
In practice if I was implementing this I'd use structs for the Client types, not classes, and hide them behind a protocol for the dictionary.  This would simplify some of the decoding as there's no need to deal with things like super.init methods

Updated answer for single heterogenous dictionary
To decode a dictionary that has a variety of types it is necessary to find a single structure that can represent all of these as this will allow Decodable to process the dictionary as a single object. The alternative would be to process it almost line-by-line, probably with JSONSerialization, which would be heavy going.  Better to let Decodable do the heavy lifting.
The way to approach this is use an enum with associated values, with a case for each of the possible types in the dictionary. This will require a custom init(from:).  To support the realistic JSON that has now been added to the question, the following approach is a viable solution...
enum AnyClient: Decodable {
   case standard(Client)
   case special(SpecialClient)
   
   
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
      do {
         let client = try container.decode(SpecialClient.self)
         self = .special(client)
      } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound {
         let client = try container.decode(Client.self)
         self = .standard(client)
      }
   }
}

Once you have this in place, the rest of the decoding becomes standard Dedcodable although with the slight overhead of supporting the inheritance in the Client / SpecialClient classes
class Client: Decodable {
   let label: String
   let clientType: String
   
   init(label: String, clientType: String) {
      self.label = label
      self.clientType = clientType
   }
}

class SpecialClient: Client {
   let specialValue: Int //just to differentiate from Client
   enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
      case label, clientType, specialValue
   }
   
   required init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      specialValue = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .specialValue)
      let label = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .label)
      let type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .clientType)
      super.init(label: label, clientType: type)
   }
}

class Group: Decodable {
   let label: String
   let id: String
}

class Object: Decodable {
   var groups: [String: Group]
   var clients: [String: AnyClient]
}


At this point you have decoded the json.  The client dictionary values are now wrapped inside an enum; this may be helpful or a hindrance moving forwards depending how you are planning to use them elsewhere, but it would be an easy task to iterate through the dictionary transform it to [String: Client].  This could even be done inside a custom .init(from:) in Object.  Susch as
   required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      self.groups = try container.decode([String : Group].self, forKey: .groups)
      let anyClients = try container.decode([String : AnyClient].self, forKey: .clients)
      
      clients = anyClients.reduce(into: [String: Client]()) { dict, item in
         switch item.value {
            case let .standard(client): dict[item.key] = client
            case let .special(client): dict[item.key] = client
         }
      }
   }

Example output
passing the provided json through:
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(Object.self, from: data)
object.groups.forEach{print($0)}
object.clients.forEach{print($0)}

provides the expected output of
(key: "GroupId1", value: __lldb_expr_161.Group)
(key: "GroupId2", value: __lldb_expr_161.Group)
(key: "ClientId1", value: __lldb_expr_161.AnyClient.standard(__lldb_expr_161.Client))
(key: "ClientId2", value: __lldb_expr_161.AnyClient.special(__lldb_expr_161.SpecialClient))


Hi, first of all your answer seems the correct way how to do it. So thank you. The problem I have is that the json I get from the backend is not in the structure you assumed (more like how I described) and thats why .nestedUnkeyedContainer does not return an array. It indeed returns nothing because it reads a dict from the json, which it does not expect and catches an error. I have to figure out how I could do it with my json structure which does not seem that easy. But now I have a better understanding what my problems are, so again thank you!

@rickmcrick I couldn't; make sense of your example structure (it's not valid JSON) so i If you can update the question with a real snippet I'm game for updating the answer.

updated the question with valid json @flanker

updated the answer for the revised json @rickmcrick

thank you very much! this approach is much cleaner than what I had before. keep up the good work!
